# Adding the role to code build to access the ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I want to give the policy to `codebuild` to access the `ecr` repository for push.

However to what should I give the policy?

I can do this manually in amazon web console though,

it's quite not clear to me in cdk.

```
   const buildProject = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, 'buildproject', {
      environment: {
        buildImage:codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_4_0,
        privileged:true, 
      },
      buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename("./buildspec.yml")
    });
    buildProject.addToRolePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
      resources: [what should be here?],
      actions: ['ecr:GetAuthorizationToken'] }
    ));
```

Comment: Sorry for missing to do accepting answers.I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `myRepository.grantPullPush(buildProject)`.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecr.Repository.html#grantwbrpullwbrpushgrantee

This will abstract away the content of the policy.

Comment: Ah , I see, it gives me the change of viewpoint. thank you very much.